# fullcalendar v5 after edit event render() don't refresh

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

when i edit a event list, it correctly reload but calendar don't refresh.
if i click in other tab and then return in calendar tab it refresh: problem with bootstrap? This is my function to init calendar

```js
function getCalendar(mydate) {
    //Date for the calendar events (dummy data)
    var date = new Date()
    var d    = date.getDate(),
        m    = date.getMonth(),
        y    = date.getFullYear()
    var calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calEv=bindEvents(mydate);
    //var calRi=bindResource(mydate);

    dCal = new calendar(calendarEl, {
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        timeZone: 'UTC',
        height: '100%',
        contentHeight: 'auto',
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
        locale: 'it',
      //Random default events
      //events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json',
        //events: bindEvents(mydate),
        //events: calEv,
        //events: evUrl,
        events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
                var evUrl     = window.apiurl+'/api/anagrafiche/tourfascecalevents/'+id_entita;
                $.ajax(evUrl, {
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                }).done(function(dati) {
                    dbgConsole("render init ev");
                    dbgConsole(dati);
                    ev=bindEvents(dati);
                    dbgConsole(ev);
                    successCallback(ev);
                }).fail(function(x,s,t) {
                    alert_error(x);
                });
        },
        //resources: bindResource(mydate),
        initialDate: dataIni,
        editable  : true,
        selectable: true,
        droppable : false, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        dateClick: function(info) {
            dbgConsole(info);//event.setProp( name, value )
            var cls=[];
            var data_fine = moment(info.dateStr, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(gg_viaggio, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            if ('undefined' == typeof grpSelected || ''==grpSelected) {
//              alert('Cancellazione data: ' + info.dateStr + ' !');
                var reqUrl     = window.apiurl+'/api/anagrafiche/tourfasce/'+id_entita;
                $.ajax(reqUrl, {
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        id_gruppo: id_gruppo,
                        id_entita: id_entita,
                        MM_delete: 'form_fascedel',
                        data_inizio: info.dateStr
                    }
                }).done(function(dati) {
                    window.tables['FasceTable'].setData();
                    dbgConsole("render");
                    //$('#h-tab').trigger('click');
                    //$('#dati-fasce-tab').trigger('click');
                    dCal.render();
                    //dCal.updateSize();
                    
                }).fail(function(x,s,t) {
                    alert_error(x);
                });
            } else {
//              alert('Imposta data: ' + info.dateStr + ' in gruppo "'+grpSelected+'" !');
                var reqUrl     = window.apiurl+'/api/anagrafiche/tourfasce/'+id_entita;
                $.ajax(reqUrl, {
                    type: 'PUT',
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        id_gruppo: id_gruppo,
                        id_entita: id_entita,
                        MM_update: 'form_fasceupd',
                        data_inizio: info.dateStr,
                        nome_periodo: grpSelected,
                        data_fine: data_fine
                    }
                }).done(function(dati) {
                    window.tables['FasceTable'].setData();
                    dbgConsole("render");
                    //$('#h-tab').trigger('click');
                    //$('#dati-fasce-tab').trigger('click');
                    dCal.render();
                    //dCal.updateSize();

                }).fail(function(x,s,t) {
                    alert_error(x);
                });
            }
//          alert('Gruppo: ' + id_gruppo + ' - Entita: "'+id_entita+ ' - Giorni: "'+gg_viaggio+'" !');
            //dCal.setOption('initialDate', '2021-06-01');
            //dCal.render();
        },
        /*
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                var testo='';
                testo=testo+'Servizio: ' + calEvent.title_serv+'\n';
                testo=testo+'Inizio: ' + calEvent.start.format()+'\n';
                testo=testo+'Fine: ' + calEvent.end.format()+'\n';
                testo=testo+'Descrizione: ' + calEvent.title+'\n';
                alert(testo);
            }
            */
    });
    //dCal.render();
    dbgConsole("Cal:")
    dbgConsole(dCal);//event.setProp( name, value )
}
```

and this is activation

```js
    $('#dati-fasce-tab').on('shown.bs.tab', function (event) {
        dCal.render();
    })
```

after 'dateClick' events are modified and reloaded but calendar not update view
P.S.: all events are type 'background'

Already exists any different method to refresh?
We are a problem to refresh on load calendar in hidden area, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to render the fullcalendar element inside the initialize function.

```
function getCalendar(mydate) {
    ...

    dCal = new calendar(calendarEl, {

    });

    dCal.render();
}
```

After that, you need to use `refetchEvents` function while an event like changing tab or save an event is firing.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents

```
dCal.refetchEvents();
```

You could face into an issue like `dCal` is undefined, then you need to add some handling like

```
if (typeof dCal !== 'undefined') {
  dCal.refetchEvents();
}
```